# How can I introduce escape characters to my JSON mapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson, escaping, jackson2

I am trying to make a simple thing using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`.

I have an object I want to translate to `String`.

```
class Car{
  String color;
  String brand;

  //... more class info
}
```

It is working fine and I get my `String` as it should but the result looks like this:

```
{"color: "blue", "brand": "toyota" }
```

Is it possible to make it look like:

```
{\"color\": \"blue\", \"brand\", \"toyota\" }
```

I'm not sure if this breaks the `JSON` expected format.

I've read the docs and seems like I can use this:

```
ObjectMapper().factory.setCharacterEscapes(...)
```

But I'm not sure how to pass it or from which repo. Any ideas?

Comment: Neither of the results are valid JSON, though, and the result you want is super-absolutely-not-valid. The only valid JSON here would be `{ "color": "blue", "brand": "toyota", ... }`. Anything else is simply not JSON at all.

Comment: JSON is supposed to have the quotes, not escaped quotes. If you take your "the result look like" and send it to a browser, then `JSON.parse(yourString)` is will parse correctly with the quotes; it will fail if you escape the quotes.

Comment: Would you like to share why you want to escape those `" "` ?

Comment: I am basically trying to make a mapper for an sort of inner object to match a SNS format https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `Jackson` to generate valid `JSON` payload and [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) to escape it.

Example code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;

public class EscapeJsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Car("blue", "Toyota"));
        String escapedJson = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(json);
        System.out.println(escapedJson);
    }
}

class Car {
    String color;
    String brand;

    // getters, setters, constructor
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{\"color\":\"blue\",\"brand\":\"Toyota\"}
```

Maven [dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text/1.8/jar):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am basically trying to make a mapper for an sort of inner object to
>   match a SNS format https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html

Here's one of the examples from that page:

```
{
  "GCM":"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"Check out these awesome deals!\",\"url\":\"www.amazon.com\"}}"
}
```

That's a JSON object with a single field named "GCM" whose value is a string. The content of the string is another JSON object.

Let's take your `Car` class as an example, and assume you want to generate this JSON as your output:

```
{
  "car": "{\"color\": \"blue\", \"brand\": \"toyota\"}"
}
```

First you'll need to convert your `Car` object to a JSON string. Then you create another JSON object and stuff the car's JSON string into a field of this outer object:

```
String carJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myCar);
Map<String, Object> outerObject = singletonMap("car", carJson);
String finalResult = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(outerObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use something like `JSONObject.quote(json)`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Car("blue", "Toyota"));
System.out.println(JSONObject.quote(json));
```

Output:

```
"{\"color\": \"blue\", \"brand\", \"toyota\" }"
```