# serialize json with escape using jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm having below json

```
{"test1":"<p>Please click here <a href="https://google.com">click here</a> for details</p>","test2":"<p><br data-mce-bogus="1"></p>"}
```

Want to add the escape for double quotes using jackson.

Desired output:

```
{\"test1\":\"<p>Please click here <a href=\\\"https://google.com\\\">click here</a> for "
                + "details</p>\",\"test2\":\"<p><br data-mce-bogus=\\\"1\\\"></p>\"}
```

And my final deserialization output needs to be `Map<String,String>`

Keys are `test1, test2`

Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want the desired output like that?

Comment: Deserializing this String to Map<String, String>. That's the reason

Comment: Your "desired output" looks like a `String`, not a `Map<String, String>`..

Comment: I am not able to deserialize with my 1st input. Because of double quotes not escaped. If I escape the double quotes, able to deserialize it. For that, asked the desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I introduce escape characters to my JSON mapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846351/how-can-i-introduce-escape-characters-to-my-json-mapper)

Comment: Based on that answer, it's giving like  {"root":"{\"test1\":\"<p>Please click here <a href=\"https://google.com\">click here</a> for details</p>\",\"test2\":\"<p><br data-mce-bogus=\"1\"></p>\"}"}  this. But I want to test1 and test2 as key in Map.

Comment: It is invalid JSON (not JSON, as it doesn't comply with the standard). You can't deserialize this; not without fixing the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have JSON as the quotes are not escaped. See http://json.org/ for what is valid and JSON works.

You SHOULD have this:

```
{"test1":"<p>Please click here <a href=\"https://google.com\">click here</a> for details</p>","test2":"<p><br data-mce-bogus=\"1\"></p>"}
```

This is not simply fixable by escaping the whole `String` either, you should preferably fix it at the source where the input `String` is generated.